# Unity Coroutine Not Waiting

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, coroutine

I am making a game where I want an overlay to appear for a specified amount of seconds before disappearing. I am using a Coroutine to do this, but it is now working. Is there a way to fix this issue or should I do it another way. I don't get any errors, but the `coverObject` doesn't display for 3 seconds and hide for 2 seconds as specified in the code.

The code:

```c#
void playRound()
{
    coverObject.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < keys - 1; i++)
    {
        GameObject instantiated = Instantiate(key);
    }
    waitSecs(3);
    coverObject.gameObject.SetActive(true);

    GameObject instantiatedCorrect = Instantiate(key);
    correctKey = instantiatedCorrect;

    waitSecs(2);
    coverObject.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
    
void waitSecs(int seconds)
{
    StartCoroutine(WaitSecsCoroutine(seconds));
}

IEnumerator WaitSecsCoroutine(int seconds) 
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
}
```

Comment: Please explain "not working", are you getting any errors? *what exactly* isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your method `playRound` will keep running while the `WaitSecsCoroutine` coroutine is yielding. This is because control is returned to the calling method as soon as a `yield return` statement is reached.

The following is happening:

- `playRound` is called
- your GameObjects get instantiated
- `waitSecs` is called
- `waitSecs` calls to coroutine `waitSecsCoroutine`
- `waitSecsCoroutine` reaches the `yield return new WaitForSeconds()`
- Control is now returned back to `waitSecs`, which in turn returns to `PlayRound`
- `playRound` continues with `coverObject.gameObject.SetActive(true);` and the subsequent code while `waitSecsCoroutine` is still waiting.

What you need to do is make `playRound` a coroutine as well, and use `yield return WaitSecsCoroutine` so the function halts its execution until `WaitSecsCoroutine` is finished:

```cs
IEnumerator playRound()
{
    coverObject.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < keys - 1; i++)
    {
        GameObject instantiated = Instantiate(key);
    }
    yield return WaitSecsCoroutine(3);//This now waits until WaitSecsCoroutine is finished
    coverObject.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    GameObject instantiatedCorrect = Instantiate(key);
    correctKey = instantiatedCorrect;
    yield return WaitSecsCoroutine(2);
    coverObject.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Note however that you can also just call the `WaitForSeconds` directly from your `playRoudn` method too once it is a coroutine, without needing a seperate function

```cs
IEnumerator playRound()
{
    coverObject.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < keys - 1; i++)
    {
        GameObject instantiated = Instantiate(key);
    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    coverObject.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    GameObject instantiatedCorrect = Instantiate(key);
    correctKey = instantiatedCorrect;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    coverObject.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Alternatively you could move the code you want to execute after the wait into your `WaitSecsCoroutine` method.

Answer (score 3):

Your Coroutine does wait ... **BUT: A Coroutine does not delay anything in the method that starts it itself.** It only delays the code within in the Coroutine!

Thus, the way you have it it will just execute the rest of the code in `playRound` without any waiting.

What you rather want to do would be running the entire thing in a Coroutine like e.g.

```c#
void playRound()
{
    StartCoroutine(PlayRoundRoutine());
}

IEnumerator PlayRoundRoutine() 
{
    coverObject.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < keys - 1; i++)
    {
        GameObject instantiated = Instantiate(key);
    }

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

    coverObject.gameObject.SetActive(true);

    GameObject instantiatedCorrect = Instantiate(key);
    correctKey = instantiatedCorrect;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);

    coverObject.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```